# Missing ia64 or itanium 64 bit build target on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, itanium

with so many versions on this subject, couldn't find an answer :

vs 2010 - professional
i have all target platforms but i can't find Itanium or IA64
i have tried googling it and couldn't find any info regarding a problem such as i have .
what am i missing ? am i wrong that x64 is not IA64 (specifically)?
or (as i was finishing this last line) i now wonder if my machine does not run on an itanuim... so why am i surprised... or it has nothing to do with the CPU of the development machine.

## update# [Link](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/237015-50-download-ia64-x86_64)

> IA64 is only for the Intel Itanium enterprise CPUs which are not x86
> compatible.

i guess it is only a mater of time till i get my hands on a testing machine this
was not to my knowlage. thought no cpu is that supperior to I7/I5 at that level of differences. 64 still supposed to be 64 bit.

Comment: Microsoft dropped all support for Itanium 5 years ago.  It is a dead product for them.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. though did u see the specs? *retorical question atleast for u... amazing ain't it ?

Comment: @HansPassant so if i did have a wish to c# on itanium special features i could not develop an application that utilizes its propeties ?

Answer (score 0):

You needed Premium or higher edition for ia64/Itanium support. And yes "ia64" is Itanium and nothing else.